# The propcedure entry point add_index_zval could not be located in the dynamic link library xampp/php/ext/php_imagic.dll

Tags: php, xampp

I installed ImageMagick and The php_imagick.dll file is xampp>php>ext .
I  encounter this error after restarting Apache.
[image]

my OS : win10 64-bit , php version: 7.4.11

and php.ini :
[image]

Comment: That sounds a lot like your version of php_imagick.dll isn't compatible with the PHP version you're running. Which version of the extension did you install?

Comment: I installed `` ImageMagick-7.0.10-53-Q16-x64-dll  ``

Comment: It's the version of **php_imagick** (not Imagemagick) that will be the issue

Comment: I used =>  php_imagick-3.4.1-7.0-ts-vc14-x64

Comment: Right - the **7.0** in that refers to PHP 7.0. You need something that targets PHP 7.4, e.g. `php_imagick-3.4.4-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip` from https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.4/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked right with this version.