# Cannot load/run Imagick on Raspberry OS (Debian 10) and PHP 8.2

Tags: php, linux, debian, imagick

## Background

Dear all,

I've installed PHP 8.2 on me Raspbian OS (PHP 8.x required by some libraries). I need to install the PHP imagemagick extension to convert images (SVG to PNG). However, I can't get it running.

## Here is what i tried

Firstly, I installed imagemagick (don't know wheather that's necessary, but just to be on the safe side):

`$ sudo apt install imagemagick`

That was successful. There are no other packages avaiable:

```
$ sudo apt install imagemagick -a
imagemagick/oldstable,now 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1+deb10u1 armhf  [installiert]
```

Secondly, I installed Imagick:

`$ sudo apt install php-imagick`

That was successful as well. There are no other packages avaiable:

```
$ sudo apt list php-imagick -a
php-imagick/oldstable,now 3.4.3-4.1 armhf [installiert]
```

I've added the following entry in my php.ini:

```php
[Imagick]
extension=imagick.so
```

Finally, I restarted apache:
`$ sudo systemctl restart apache2`

During troubleshooting, I even restarted php:
`$ sudo service php8.2-fpm reload`

## Problem and troubleshooting so far

Imagick doesn't show up, neither when I try `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep imagick` nor `php -m | grep imagick`.

Saying that, of course `$im = new \Imagick();` results in a

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Imagick" not found`.

I've studied web pages (including [php error: Class 'Imagick' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790191/php-error-class-imagick-not-found)) and manuals for more than two hours now without any success. Any help/hint is highly appreciated!

## Edit: Hints found so far

Maybe one hint is that imagick.so was installed in the directory `/usr/lib/php/20180731`, while the current php extensions directory (according to php.ini) is `/usr/lib/php/20220829`. Copying the file to `20220829` (and restarting the services) didn't help.

Another hint might be that `/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d` contains a (link file) `20-imagick.ini` (pointing to `/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/imagick.ini`), while `/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d` doesn't contain such a link, and `/etc/php/8.2/mods-available` doesn't contain an `imagick.ini` file. Same is applicable for `/etc/php/x.y/apache2/conf.d`. That seems suspicious, so I copied the following files

```
/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/imagick.ini -> /etc/php/8.2/mods-available/imagick.ini [content: extension=imagick.so]
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini -> /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-imagick.ini -> /etc/php/8.2/apache2/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini -> /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
/usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so -> /usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so
```

After `$ sudo systemctl restart apache2` when I run `$ php -m | grep imagick` I now get

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so: undefined symbol: add_next_index_zval), /usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Maybe for some reason apt install and/or php-imagick think that my current php version is 7.3, so it updated the wrong files and took the wrong shared library (imagick.so), while it is 8.2 (7.3 is still installed, but inactive and 8.2 is active)?

Found this link here, that at least matches the error message: [The propcedure entry point add_index_zval could not be located in the dynamic link library xampp/php/ext/php_imagic.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65521238/the-propcedure-entry-point-add-index-zval-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-li)

Possible solution: I have to get Imagick version>=3.5.0, according to the change log https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=imagick, in order to have PHP 8.x supported (hopefully 8.2).

Comment: Did you edit the correct `php.ini`? There's one for CLI and one for webserver/Apache. A `.php` page on your webserver having `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` should tell you which `php.ini` to edit

Comment: Yes. I've edited `Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini`, according to `phpinfo();`.

Comment: And I guess Imagick doesn't show up on that phpinfo page either?!

Comment: No, it doesn't show up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Main problem: Certificates of repository not installed

The main problem was that I had installed PHP 8.2 from an additional repository, as PHP 8.x is not yet supported by the Raspberr Pi Foundation, but I needed PHP 8.x for some extensions. The repository is fine, but I hadn't added the some certificates, so `apt` couldn't load all required files from this repository.

And you get lots of headache, when you can't load required files from a repository.

## Step by step solution (for Debian 10 Buster)

Here is what I did in order to solve (or, to be more specific, to avoid) the problem.

### Clean connection to repository

1. Add repository gpg to your list if trusted repositories.

```
$ sudo wget /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
$ echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

2. Update apt package information
   This step is imporant, don't omit it.

```
$ sudo apt update
```

3. Follow instructions of the repository provider
   Unfortunately, I wasn't aware of the following steps, and this caused my problems. According to https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install lsb-release ca-certificates curl
$ sudo curl -sSLo /usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Otherwise, the required cerficicates are not installed, and apt doesn't download all files from the repository (although it downloaded some - I have no idea why this is the case).

### Get phpize

4. Get phpize
   You need `phpize` to install `Imagick` later. phpize is included in the package `pho-dev`. When I tried this before solving the certificate issue (see above), I failed to do so due to package requiremens restrictions. Make sure to have the repostories properly connected (see above).

The error message was similar to this one (I had to translate it and hope I got it right):

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcre2-dev : Depends: libpcre2-8-0 (= 10.32-5) but 10.34-7+0~20191219.5+debian9 is to be installed
```

As soon the certificate issue was solved, the following command installed `phpsize` für PHP 8.2:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-dev
```

### Install PECL

5. Install PECL
   Rather then installing installing `imagick` with `apt`, I installed it by using `PECL`, as recommended in the PHP documentation.
   First, I had to download go-pear.phar.
   Second, I installed it

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
```

I moved `go-pear.phar` to a directory `~/Downloads/pear/`.

```
$ sudo php ~/Downloads/pear/go-pear.phar
Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation.  To
change individual locations, type the number in front of the
directory.  Type 'all' to change all of them or simply press Enter to
accept these locations.

 1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : /usr
 2. Temporary directory for processing            : /tmp/pear/install
 3. Temporary directory for downloads             : /tmp/pear/install
 4. Binaries directory                            : /usr/bin
 5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : /usr/share/php
 6. Documentation directory                       : /usr/docs
 7. Data directory                                : /usr/data
 8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : /usr/cfg
 9. Public Web Files directory                    : /usr/www
10. System manual pages directory                 : /usr/man
11. Tests directory                               : /usr/tests
12. Name of configuration file                    : /etc/pear.conf

1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue:
```

It is important to run this with sudo, otherwise user-specific directories are suggested.
I pressed `Enter` to continue.

### Install imagemagick and Imagick

6. Install imagemagick

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev libmagickcore-dev
```

7. Install imagick (via PECL)

```
$ sudo pecl install imagick
```

During this installation, `phpize` is required to compile imagick. `phpize` had the wrong path for `sed` configured (see the first lines in the file `phpize`).

To be on the save side, I copied `sed` as (hard) link

```
$ sudo ln /bin/sed /usr/bin/sed
```

## Disconnect repository added as first step

If you wish to disconnect the repository sury.org/php, you have to execute this commands. I'm **not recommending** this, as the possible updates or changes of the software installed depends on this repository.

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

Comment: I know very little about this. But there are two versions of Imagemagick, 6 and 7. Did you install the correct one for the version requirements of Imagick?

Comment: I got version ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 arm 20190101

Comment: Perhaps it wants Imagemagick 7?.  Also does Imagick and PHP know where the Imagemagick version is located.  They probably need to all be in your $Path environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the problem is already solved, everything works fine.

Comment: You are commenting the solution description. Please scroll up. Thank you.